# How to recover this Linux partition?

Tags: linux, windows, partition, ext3

I have this netbook, where the partition table looks like this

```
~$ fdisk netbook.dd 
Warning: invalid flag 0x0000 of partition table 5 will be corrected by w(rite)

Command (m for help): p

Disk netbook.dd: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x89c52b31

     Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
netbook.dd1   *        2048      616447      307200    7  HPFS/NTFS
netbook.dd2          616448   287338589   143361071    7  HPFS/NTFS
netbook.dd3       589484032   620941311    15728640    7  HPFS/NTFS
netbook.dd4       287338590   589473044   151067227+   5  Extended

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Command (m for help):
```

There used to be a en EXT3 Linux partition on it, where GRUB would boot from. Now something has happened, so it is gone. I assume there also have been a swap partition, but not sure.

Can anyone make anything out of this? Or perhaps suggestions on what I can try to get the EXT3 partition back with data on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After fixing the partition table with fdisk, just pressing `w` I was able to recover everything using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

Comment: TestDisk is definetely the tool people look for in such a situation, +1

Answer (score 5):

Like it says, writing the partition table back should set the correct flags - however there must be a reason they changed to 0 in the first lpace - you may find that you have to run an fsck on the partition - and even then the disk may not be recoverable.

Comment: Ok, now I have written the partition table with `w`, and now it doesn't give any warnings. But how do I mount this Extended partition?  If I delete it with `d` and create a new with `n` and set the type to `83 Linux`, I still can't mount it.

Comment: erm, if you deleted it then you'll have a lot of trouble accessing any data on it unless you recreate it with **exactly** the same settings as before. Something has changed the partition map - it may have changed data on the partition too. Try running fsck on it first. - just seen your later update below

Answer (score 4):

[gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) has the ability to scan your disks for "lost" partitions  [of most types](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/features.php).

If you weren't able to remember exactly where it was (and didn't lucky like you did), the `rescue` command in gparted will do the work for you.